# Appending an array with constantly updating values from interval function

Tags: javascript, arrays, stream, intervals

I'm using some code I've written to pull a value from an API every second. I want to add the value I pull to an array, then constantly add another element to that array with the new value every second. Here's what I have

```
    var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
    API.getdata(function (err, data) {
        var ask = Number(money.lowestAsk);
        var entry = [ask];
        });
    });
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
}, 25000);
```

So, ideally, what I'm trying to do is create a growing array called "entry" which constantly adds the value "ask" to the end of the array every second for 25 seconds. Is this possible?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If `getdata` is async then you cannot guarantee that you can put an item in every second. Perhaps look into `Promise.all`

Comment: You need to define entry outside of the interval, also the order is not guaranteed... `var entries = [];
var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
  API.getdata(function(err, data) {
    var ask = Number(money.lowestAsk);
    entries.push(ask);
  });
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(intervalID);
}, 25000);`

Comment: You pass *err* and *data* to the callback but don't seem to use them. `var entry = [ask]` goes nowhere, *entry* must be in an outer scope so `entry.push(ask)` *might* be what you want.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7bap8vwd/1/ - not tested

Comment: Thanks for your help here, this is taking me in good directions